# Cant figure out why my Vlookup isnt inserting into the cell

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

Still learning this. Trying to insert a Vlookup into a cell but with Variable sheet, and table dependent upon an option button selected earlier. If I just do & i & it works just fine but when I add & wb.ws.i & it doesn't even print to the cell. When I hover over activecell.formula = it says activecell.formula = "". Not sure how to fix this.

```
'Set the workbook and worksheet as a variable
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
 
'Set the WB and WB variable to the worksheet and workbook needed
    Set WB = Workbooks("Database.xlsx")
    
    If CPWireless_Radial_Search.Value = True Then Set WS = WB.Sheets("Wireless")
    If CPLandline_Radial_Search.Value = True Then Set WS = WB.Sheets("Landline")
    If CPExtension_Radial_Search.Value = True Then Set WS = WB.Sheets("Extensions")

'In Cell C2 Eneter this VLOOKUP Formula
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(A2, " & WB.Name & "!" & i & ",3,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(A2," & WB.Name & "!" & i & ",3,FALSE),""No Charge"")"
```

```
'Find what table matches the (Option Button)
    table1 = Workbooks("Database.xlsx").Sheets("Wireless").ListObjects(1).Name
    Table2 = Workbooks("Database.xlsx").Sheets("Landline").ListObjects(1).Name
    Table3 = Workbooks("Database.xlsx").Sheets("Extensions").ListObjects(1).Name
    
    If CPWireless_Radial_Search.Value = True Then i = table1
    If CPLandline_Radial_Search.Value = True Then i = Table2
    If CPExtension_Radial_Search.Value = True Then i = Table3
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `WB.WS.i`? Your provided code doesn't show what `i` is.

Comment: It is Identifing the Array in the vlookup that is in another workbook but the sheet can change depending on the option button selected.

Comment: The VLOOKUP formula expects an *address*. Here that would include the workbook name, the sheet name, and the range address on that sheet.

Comment: isnt that what i am doing by adding wb.ws.i?

Comment: Why Does ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(A2," & i & ",4,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(A2," & i & ",4,FALSE),""No Charge"")"? It will enter the correct table but not on the right Workbook or sheet.

Comment: I added i to my question area

Comment: 1. WS is already defined as WB.<someWorksheet name>.  Your use of WB.WS is already incorrect-just WS alone gets you to the right workbook.  2) Your use of WS.i implies there is an object property called "i" defined in the WS object.  Microsoft's documentation of the worksheet object includes no such variable.  How, exactly, did you think it was getting defined?  We cannot see it in your code, and it is not part of the Excel object model.

Comment: Ok didnt know about the ws but it makes sence. i ends up being defined bu the option button they choose which when i hover over it show the correct table. would it be better if i just supplied the entire code?

Comment: What's your expected formula?

Comment: This is what is currently working--ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(A2," & WS.Name & "!" & i & ",3,FALSE),""No Charge"")" -- and here is the output--=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Wireless!Table1,3,FALSE),"No Charge")

Comment: Try `=IF(VLOOKUP(A2," & WB.Name & "!" & i & ",3,FALSE),""No Charge"")`

Comment: I get as an output =IF(VLOOKUP(A2, Database.xlsx!Table1[#Data],3,FALSE),"No Charge") but #data is nowhere to be found

Comment: `#Data` means just the data rows. _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Choose an account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: ok cool. I figured it out ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(A2, " & WB.Name & "!" & i & ",3,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(A2," & WB.Name & "!" & i & ",3,FALSE),""No Charge"")"